# How do I get git to recognize mailmap for users without email-adresses?

Tags: git

I use git, and have entries in mailmap that remaps the various email-addresses people use to the "canonical" name and email for that user. However, I also have some historical commits in which there's no email at all, but merely a username, such as "tommy".

I want to remap these too, to the canonical name and email for that user, but have been unable to do so. I've tried both:

```
Canonical_name tommy
Canonical <canonical@email> tommy <>
Canonical tommy <>
```

but none of these seem to have any effect at all.

Edit to clarify: I don't have any wish of changing the history. I just want the canonical names displayed when prettyprinting with %aN which remaps names using mailmap. This works -perfect- for the case where 3 different email-adresses are supposed to map to one canonical name. But not at all for the case where the original comitter didn't supply an email-address at all.

Comment: What version are you using? From the Git release notes for version 1.6.2: `The location of .mailmap file can be configured, and its file format was enhanced to allow mapping an incorrect e-mail field as well.` A quick test using version 1.7.8 works correctly; the author info is mapped when I use `Tommy Lee <tommy.lee@pamelas-secrets.com> tommy <>` in `.mailmap`. This might be a behavioral difference between versions.

Answer (score 1):

The second line of syntax attempted by the OP works on my machine (git version 2.33.1):

```
Canonical <canonical@email> tommy <>
```

Perhaps this was a feature added to git in the decade since the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

As commits are already in the tree, they will not change -- it would break the history's integrity!

Your only option, if you really want to do that, is to use `git filter-branch`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git) for more details. But you will definitely alter your repository, which means other people using this same repository as a base will also be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a fake e-mail address like `none@mycompany.com`.

On the other hand: if the people are still in the project, they **will** have an existing E-Mail address now. If they are no longer there: why bother with the address? You could take a fake address in that case...